# Sign in with Apple using from Firebase Web SDK: getting null displayName

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I've set up "Sign in with Apple" using **Firebase Web SDK** as described on this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple

I'm getting everything returned correctly from the SDK except for **user.displayName** returning **null**.

This is an excerpt of the code I'm using:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');

provider.addScope('email');
provider.addScope('name');

firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
    
        console.log(result.user); // displays user.displayName = null

    });
```

I know that Apple only returns name information on first authentication with the same app, unless you go to your Apple security settings / "sign in with apple" and cancel the association with that app.

Important clue: I can see from the **network logs** that google is correctly returning firstName, lastName and displayName to my web app, so **the problem is on the Firebase web SDK** not returning it to me.

I've googled everything, but no I've found no solution except for using a different library.

Anyone faced and solved this issue?

**Notes**:

- I've already successfully set up a similar "Sign in with Google" using the same Firebase Web SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin
- I'm using Firebase compat library v10.7.2 as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#window-compat

Comment: It sounds like you're convinced that the problem is with Firebase and not with your code.  In that case, there's nothing the volunteers of Stack Overflow can do to help you.  You should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) and report the problem directly to them.  Stack Overflow is not a site for general discussion - it's for questions and answers.  As such, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @DougStevenson maybe I should have written "the problem is how to extract that information from the Firebase web SDK". I can edit the question if you think this will be more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: The SDK clearly provides a single way to get at the info.  If it's not there, I don't think you have a reasonable workaround.  What you really have is a bug report for the SDK, if you can prove that it's just doing the wrong thing. Filing the bug report is the best thing for everyone. But if you really are looking for a workaround for this incorrect behavior, you should be clear about that.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your advice. I've sent a bug report to Firebase, together with a very simple live example (https://app.miafattura.it/appletest.html) that anyone can test.